# Ping not working

Tags: linux, networking, ip

Ping is not working to and from this IP to my computer.

inet addr:10.125.104.4  Bcast:10.125.111.255  Mask:255.255.240.0

My computer is like this

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.125.65.75
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.125.64.6
```

We both CAN reach the common gateway IP , 10.125.96.6 .

What should I check ? What is the barrier in sending info if we both have a common gateway that is pingable ?

Besides I can login to a intermediate server and ssh to this server also !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I use a sniffer on both machines to see what's on the wire. PING means that a request was sent out AND the response came back. The lack of PING by itself, without observation of the traffic on the wire doesn't tell you if the problem is the loss of the request on the way to the remote host or the loss of the response coming back.

My gut says that an intermediate device with a firewall rule (or ACL) or a host-based firewall is your problem, but w/o seeing the traffic on the wire I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 4):

Computers are in different subnets.

do traceroute. Its show how ping routed.

```
traceroute 10.125.104.4
```

At last, first hop must be local router.

Ability of ping common IP address not guarentee appropriate routing.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your subnet masks are different; one host doesn't believe the other is on the local segment as a result of this.

**Update**: Is Evan right here, these are completely separate segments?  I was thrown by the "common gateway" comment.

Comment: Nope. The second subnet isn't located inside the first subnet-- those are distinct subnets (10.125.96.0/20, spanning 10.125.96.0 to 10.125.111.255, and 10.125.64.0/22 spanning 10.125.64.0 to 10.125.67.255).

Comment: Heh heh... "Is Evan right here" on an IPv4 subnetting question? Hahahaha! http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/server-fault-wiki-how-does-subnetting-work/49836#49836

Answer (score 2):

The subnet shouldn't matter if the firewall is configured right a.a.a.a/24 can ping b.b.b.b/32 if properly configured. Like Evan said a sniffer to find where the failure is is the best place to start.